# Multiple missiles not being saved to a custom loadout

Tags: h.a.w.x.-2

I used to play most of my games with Heat Seekers, Multiple Missiles and Unguided Bombs. After the update, however, some of the planes I had such a custom loadout for lost MMs, only having HSM and UG. Saving a custom loadout with MMs and UGs for this plane only gives UGs, not MMs. I suspect it is because the UGs occupy the pylons that would hold MMs instead of the pylons I set them to (which cannot hold MMs but can hold UGs). This bug is not exclusive to UGs and also happens with other weapons that occupy the same pylons.

What's particularly annoying is that it happens with Su-37 Terminator, my favorite plane. F35 Lightning does not suffer from that bug and is a capable replacement, but I would like to go back to Su-37. Is there any way to put MMs and UGs on Su-37 and other planes that lost this option after the update?

Comment: Was it a bug that you could put MMs on the SU-37 in the first place?  If it was, sounds like the patch just fixed the bug.

Comment: @fbueckert no, it wasn't. You can put them and the bombs on a plane, but they disappear when you save the loadout. If they weren't compatible they wouldn't show up in the list.

Comment: Ok, then.  Might want to re-word it as it sounds like you're using a loophole to put them on to the same point. "I suspect it is because the UGs occupy the pylons that would hold MMs."

Comment: @fbueckert I've clarified it. The problem is that there is only 1 set of pylons that can hold MMs, and UGs are taking them up instead of other pylons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the bug only appears in the custom loadout editing menu, saving the loadout and starting a mission with it will let you have all the weapons.

Below is a workaround I devised without realizing this.

Getting around the bug is possible, though a bit involved. You need to get the weapons to be resolved in the right order - MMs before UGs (This bug happens with most weapons except for HSM and JSM, but I will be referring to the second weapon as UG for simplicity).

1. Enter Plane Mastery and select Su-37
2. Open custom loadout
3. Choose 2 Precision Missiles, 2 Precision Bombs and 2 UGs (or your weapon of choice, substitute PM or PB for UGs if you want them to be in your loadout) in that order.
4. Remove PMs and PBs and equip MMs. You may also equip HSM, JSM or another weapon that fits the available pylons.
5. **Save** the loadout.
6. Open custom loadout to check to see that the weapons are showing up properly, **quit** menu without saving.
7. Start a mission with the custom loadout. You will be missing MMs.
8. Quit the mission
9. Enter Hangar.
10. Open the custom loadout, MMs and UGs will be present.
11. **Save** the loadout.

The weapons have now been saved properly, you should be able to start a mission and have all of your weapons.

Entering the custom loadout menu after doing so will cause MMs to disappear again, but don't worry, unless you save the loadout you will still have the missiles available for use in missions.